# SQL Delete all but top x

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete all values apart from the top x value but I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

My query:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.cake
 where dbo.cake.pie not in (select top 500 * from dbo.cake
 where createdDate >= '2007-01-01'
 and createdDate < '2008-01-01')
```

The error I get is:

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to

```
DELETE FROM dbo.cake
 where dbo.cake.pie not in (select top 500 pie from dbo.cake
 where createdDate >= '2007-01-01'
 and createdDate < '2008-01-01')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer when it lets me. holy.. this query has taken 5 minutes so far to run and it's still going!

Comment: You might want to add index on createdDate column. I am assuming pie has Primary key already.

Comment: In all honesty I don't even know how to do that. I get this error after attempting to do the query :(..  Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_donuts_tastenice". The conflict occurred in database "food_qa", table "dbo.Typesoffood", column 'cakeid'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: It means that you have ether to DELETE all the dbo.Typesoffood records that are using your pies, or remove FK_donuts_tastenice, or make cakeid column nullable on dbo.Typesoffood table.

Comment: The error means you have child records for some of the records you want to delete. Your business need dictate what to do next but under you should NEVER drop the FK. That is the sure way to have data intgrity problems. You should either rewrite the queries to delete from the child table first, rewrite the query to only drop records that do not have child records or set up cascade delte (often a bad choice, FKs exist to keep you from dropping records when they have data in child tables and it is only a good choice if the tables are small and you won't need the child records for reporting).

Answer (score 4):

Try putting the field in the subquery

```
DELETE FROM dbo.cake
 where dbo.cake.pie not in (select top 500 pie from dbo.cake
 where createdDate >= '2007-01-01'
 and createdDate < '2008-01-01')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY foo) FROM dbo.cake)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN>500
AND createdDate >= '2007-01-01'
and createdDate < '2008-01-01'
```